# SQL server convert a column from string to date

Tags: sql-server, string, date

I have a column `stocked` as a `nvarchar(50)` containing dates of this format `('yyyy/mm/dd')`, i'd like to convert it to date so i can do some dateadds to make further comparaisons.

Nothing that i've seen so far has been working (was a lot about casts and converts) and always resulted in stuff like that :

> "Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."

Comment: First database design mistake: _I have a column stocked as a nvarchar(50) containing dates_ Change the column to be a date

Comment: mysql or sql server?

Comment: Use [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Comment: @DIe No SQLServer I think#

Comment: what is your sql server version?

Comment: ...and what would you like to do with invalid strings?

Comment: Imagine you have '2017/13/20' and '2017/20/13' in the same column, what would you expect from conversion?

Comment: I misread or maybe there was a mistaken tag... anyways, if your SQL  Server versión is 2008 or higher take a look at ['Convert'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) function for SQL Server

Comment: State what you tried, present sample data, without either let alone both we might be unable to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have data that cannot be converted properly. You can use a query like below to see the problem data( this works in SQL server 2012 and above)

```
declare @tableName table(stocked nvarchar(50));
insert into @tableName values
('2017/12/31'),('2017/11/11'),('2017/11/13'),('2017/13/11');
SET DATEFORMAT ymd;  

select
stocked,
TRY_PARSE(stocked as datetime)
from @tableName
where TRY_PARSE(stocked as datetime) is NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

> [ISDATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isdate-transact-sql) ( expression )
>
> Returns 1 if the expression is a valid date, time, or datetime value;
>   otherwise, 0.

Answer (score 0):

Basicly i had an excel table that i inserted into SQL server 2014, didn't manage do convert the data to date at the insertion but i guess it would be less of a pain working on the way of insertion than convert it later on